# Is it possible to use a quantum computer simulation to perform a cyber attack?

Tags: algorithms, quantum-computing

Is it possible to use a quantum computer and or a simulation to perform a cyber attack on classic computers? This is part of a research objective I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what your objective is. For example, if your objective is to break a factorization-based cryptography protocol, then you can use [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) to quickly find the factorization and break the protocol.

However, there are many other cryptography protocols, many of which are believed to be secure even against a quantum computer.

**Note:** a simulation of a quantum computer in a regular computer won't help you at all. Simulating a quantum computer is much much more expensive than what it will allow you to do.

Comment: How are they secure? The whole research is about finding a quantum safe encryption algorithm, even sha256 on which they used Grover's algorithm to reduce the searching possibilities is no longer secure. So now instead of 2^256 we have 2^128 possibilities.